# Relative performance of geom_raster()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an `R`/`ggplot2` use case that seems to call for `geom_raster`: a regular Cartesian grid with z-values at x, y locations. I've been using `geom_tile`, and I expected a performance improvement from switching to `geom_raster`. But I don't seem to be seeing one...

Here's a toy example (but about the right size), using `base` graphics:

```
n <- m <- 200
x <- 1:n
y <- 1:m
f <- function(x, y) 10 * sin(x / n) * cos(y / m)
z <- outer(x, y, f)
system.time(image(z))

   user  system elapsed 
  0.998   0.007   1.023
```

Here it is with `ggplot2`:

```
obs <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
obs$z <- as.numeric(as.list(z))
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(obs, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z))
system.time(show(p + geom_tile()))

   user  system elapsed 
  7.328   0.891   8.187 

require(ggExtra)
system.time(show(p + geom_raster()))

   user  system elapsed 
  7.000   0.637   7.799
```

So, a modest gain, but nowhere near what I was expecting. Am I doing it wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `geom_raster` from the latest `ggplot2` ([dev version](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Developing-ggplot2-using-github), currently), not the buggy prototype in `ggExtra` (this package is now deprecated, btw).

Doing so, I get better results, 4.705 vs. 1.416 (elapsed). Quite an improvement.

Edit: it turns out that `?geom_raster` in `ggplot2` already offers a better benchmark, on my system

```
benchplot(base + geom_raster())
       step user.self sys.self elapsed
1 construct     0.006    0.004   0.010
2     build     0.887    0.212   1.109
3    render     0.449    0.119   0.584
4      draw     0.108    0.005   0.141
5     TOTAL     1.450    0.340   1.844
> benchplot(base + geom_tile())
       step user.self sys.self elapsed
1 construct     0.016    0.005   0.026
2     build     1.031    0.329   1.365
3    render     1.021    0.297   1.318
4      draw     0.987    0.041   1.040
5     TOTAL     3.055    0.672   3.749
```