# Overlay shapefile over Raster in Multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, gis, raster, shapefile

I am trying overlay the shapefile of south asia on top of multiple raster plots using the code as below:  'a' is a multilayered raster file. Here is the link to the data (917KB size) [Test_Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14Q7n_Qs26HHnNNutjqqqU_3XwZlZT-4h)

```
ras <- list.files("/filepath/", pattern = "\\.tif$", full=TRUE)
s <- stack(ras)
south_asia  <- readOGR('/filepath/south_asia.shp')  #to import shapefile
cropped <- crop(x = s, y = extent(south_asia))          #crop raster
plot(cropped)
plot(south_asia, add=TRUE)
```

This code gives me one shapefile and multiple raster plots. How do i overlay the shapefile on top of the rasters?
[image]
Any help will be appreciated.
P.S: They are in same CRS
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your data? Otherwise nobody can replicate your case and help you.

Comment: Uploaded the data. Kindly check the files

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227182/how-to-set-use-ggplot2-to-map-a-raster) helps you.

Comment: Thnks for your help

Answer (score 3):

First, please try to give a reproducible example instead of a link to download files externally!

If you manually construct the plot (e.g. using `par` with `base` plotting) you can get your desired behaviour:

```
library(raster)

## testdata

# shapefile
shp <- getData(country='IND', level=1)

# raster 
r <- getData('alt', country='IND', mask=TRUE)

# create 4 layer rasterstack
rs <- stack(r,r,r,r)

## finally plot

# 2 rows, 2 cols
par(mfrow=c(2,2))


# loop layers
for (ii in 1:nlayers(rs)){

  plot(subset(rs,ii), main=names(rs)[ii])
  plot(shp, add=T)


}
```

#### Edit:

Use `plot(subset(rs,ii), main=names(rs)[ii])` in the loop to plot the respective layer.

The result:

[image]

Comment: Though your results is what i wanted. Still i am getting the same figure as above (mine). Please try the  reproducible example as i edited the codes.

Comment: The key in my approach is to use `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` to set up the plot and the visualize each layer independently instead of plotting the entire rasterstack at once. Now I see that I've included an error, as I plot the same raster over and over within the loop - instead it should be the layer `ii` in each iteration. I'll update

Comment: ```plot(subset(rs,ii), main=names(rs)[ii])``` is doing the job but i get one plot on the screen. The last plot is the last layer on the screen. I want all the plots in one figure and not individual figures. Kindly update

Comment: @Dipu did you run `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` prior?

Comment: Thank you very much..i forgot to run that code    Yes...it worked.. i was wondering if you can also suggest the code for one color bar for multiple plots and the color bar to be positioned below the figure with legend names with unites like Temperature (^oC)

Comment: Things start to get a bit cumbersome using base plotting. You can do it, but maybe you want to check out [rasterVis](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the argument **addfun** in the plot option for raster stack/brick
For example:

```
# Function to add shapefile "shp_file" on each raster plot
add_shp=function(){plot(shp_file, bg="transparent", add=TRUE)}

#Plot selected raster of a raster stack, rs
plot(rs[[c(1:5)]],col=tim.colors(5),addfun=add_shp)
```

This will add shapefile **shp_file** to each of the 5 plots from the rasterstack **rs**.