# Heat Map in ggplot(), getting all the layers plotted

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, heatmap, r-sf

I am making a heat map of flooding incidents in the UK. I am following the example listed [here](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-crime-heatmap-in-r/). However, I am using a different base map from the example and it won't show up on the map. For my base map I use shapefiles provided by the UK gov, found [here](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/local-administrative-units-level-1-january-2018-full-extent-boundaries-in-united-kingdom), and named it `uk.shp`, an `sf` object. Flooding data is proprietary and I cannot share but the original format is polygon shapefile. I then turn those shapefiles into gridded points so I can plot a continuous heat map, this `sf` object is named `pt.shp`.

Here is the the base map, original shapefile, and gridded points overlaid for context. You can see there are many floods here, often laying under the same point. I constructed a grid sf object that repeats a given point and uses flood ID as the unique identifier. Below is an example of the data with proprietary information removed. One possible issue I can think of is `st_intersection` returned the lat and long of the flooding shapefile (which I set as the mapping `aes()`) but the point's mapping coords are listed in the geometry column of the data.
[image]

[image]

However, when I use `stat_density2d()` with my base map, the continuous plot disappears. Below is my plotting code w/ each mapping iteration.

```
# base map plots
base <- ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data=uk.shp)
```

[image]

```
# Plot density of the points
ggplot()+
  stat_density2d(data=pt.shp, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill = ..density..), geom='tile', contour = F)
```

[image]

```
# base map shows up w/o density map? But legend exists so it is being mapped... 
base +
    stat_density2d(data=pt.shp, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill = ..density..), geom='tile', contour = F, alpha = .5) +
    viridis::scale_fill_viridis(option='inferno')
```

[image]

Some issues are clear, like the plotting window of the heatmap has different dimensions than the base map. However, my main issues is I can't overlay the two plots and I don't know why.

Comment: You are much more likely to receive a useful answer if you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33234951/9084488?